# Access amplify env variables inside lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Is it possible to access the env variables inside lambda functions with amplify?

Here is an list with available env variables:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html

From this list i need for example AWS_BRANCH. How do i access it inside the function?

I tried with `process.env.AWS_BRANCH` but its undefined.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way than what I describe.

This [comment](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/2227#issuecomment-561160049) uses `jq` to inject the build environment variable directly into your cloud formation.

```
jq '.Resources.LambdaFunction.Properties.Environment.Variables = .Resources.LambdaFunction.Properties.Environment.Variables + {"AWS_BRANCH": $AWS_BRANCH}' your-func-cloudformation-template.json > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" your-func-cloudformation-template.json
```

You can put key-value pairs into the `parameters.json` file that sits next to the Lambda's `xxxxxx-cloudformation-template.json` file to inject the AWS_BRANCH value. e.g.

You'd need to inject that into the build script, perhaps via `amplify.yml`.

**Second approach**

You could modify the above to update an existing key in the `parameters.json` file. That will add it to your cloudformation and you can pull it into the resources environment vars. That seems a bit cleaner:

**parameters.json**

```
{
  awsBranch: AWS_BRANCH
}
```

But then you still need to augment the build to inject the variable. The "best" way (until you find a better way) in my opinion would be to hard-code the value into each "environment" (e.g. `dev`, `prod`) in the `amplify/team-provider-info.json` file. Add it to the resources that need it and the value will be exposed to CloudFormation. Next, update the Lambda's CloudFormation and add it to the parameters and lambda environment vars.

Update your `xxxxx-cloudformation-template.json` file to have the property.

```
"Parameters": {
  "awsBranch": {
    "Type": "String",
    "Description": "AWS_BRANCH from build environment vars"
  },
```

Then in the lambda resource, convert the parameter to an environment var:

```
"Environment": {
  "Variables": {
    "AWS_BRANCH": {
      "Ref": "awsBranch"
    },
```

And then in your typescript code you can just access the parameter `process.env.AWS_BRANCH`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it didnt helped me. The build throws an error. However i managed it on a different way. i will post my answer

Answer (score 0):

I have found an workaround. I do it with the hooks: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/project/command-hooks/

Here i use the `pre-push.js` hook that gets executed before the build.

Here is how i inject the environment variable `AWS_BRANCH` into my lambda:

First i need to read it:

```
let jsonFile = require("../backend/function/mylambda/mylambda-cloudformation-template.json")
```

Then i edit it:

```
jsonFile.Resources.LambdaFunction.Properties.Environment.Variables["AWS_BRANCH"] = process.env.AWS_BRANCH
```

Now i write the file back:

```
fs.writeFileSync("./amplify/backend/function/mylambda/mylambda-cloudformation-template.json", JSON.stringify(jsonFile))
```

This actually works. Now i can access `process.env.AWS_BRANCH` inside my lambda

Comment: That looks like a great approach, glad you found it.